# Run python command inside a bash script and get the result

Tags: python, bash, shell

I would like to run a python command that return `true` or `false` inside a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

Some stuff...
boolean = $(python -c "bool(...operations...)")
```

The code above is just to sketch the idea. I need boolean to be `false` or `true` (bash boolean values) depending on the result of `...operations...`. The code above is not working: `boolean` results to be an empty variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bool=$(python -c 'print(bool("abc"))')` works as expected.

Note that this will return `True` or `False` not `true` or `false` (i.e., capitalized).

Answer (score 1):

[xonsh](https://xon.sh/) shell should be useful for such mixing of bash and python

Answer (score 1):

Bash has no preconception on boolean values, but if you need your `bool` to be either `false` or `true`, then you can use this snippet

```
bool=$(python -c 'print("true" if ...operations... else "false")')
```

E.G.,

```bash
$ for a in 4 5 ; do
>    bool=$(python -c 'print("true" if '$a' == 4 else "false")')
>    echo $bool
> done
true
false
$
```